# Android. Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON не работает

Tags: android

Изучаю широковещательные сообщения. В книге Д.Н Колисниченко  - "программирование для андроид" есть пример где по нажатию кнопки камеры вызывется сервис. Но он у меня че то не работает. В чем проблема? Думал в файле манифесте, поэтому куда я только не тыкал там  ниче не работает. Или я не знаю что такое именно кнопка камеры (физичесская или на дисплее) или не пойму че не так. Вот код из примера:

```js
MainActivity.java
//......................................................
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    MyReceiver iReceiver = new MyReceiver();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        IntentFilter iFilter =  new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON);

        iFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON);

        registerReceiver(iReceiver, iFilter);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(iReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
//.....................................................
MyReceiver.java
//....................................................
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context rcvContext, Intent rcvIntent) {
        String action = rcvIntent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON)) {

            rcvContext.startService(new Intent(rcvContext,
                    MyService.class));
        }
    }
}
//..........................................................
MyService.java
//..........................................................
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service started...",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed...",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ivarious.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
            <service android:name=".MyService"></service>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.extra.KEY_EVENT" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
        </receiver>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Может имеется в виду кнопка у Вас в приложении, по нажатии на которую необходимо открыть камеру? Тогда в `onClick` ей пишете  `Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON, null);
startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Та нет вроде. в конце главы пишет так " Приемник анализирует полученное действие. Если нажата кнопка камеры, то будет
запущен сервис (служба)  MyService , описанный в файле MyService.java. Код этого
файла представлен в листинге 11.6. Вам нужно изменить только первую строчку,
она должна выглядеть так:
package com.samples.my_receiver;
В этой главе рассмотрели создание потоков, служб и широковещательных прием-
ников. В следующей мы поговорим о создании анимации в Android-приложениях."